# With WxWidgets, is the wxTextCtrl one-size-fits-all?

Tags: wxwidgets

When working with guis of different kinds, I am used to the distinction of text field or text entry box versus text box.  That is there is one type of object for the multi-line word processor style text box and another type of object for a single line, quite often non-scrollable text field / text entry box.  Does wxTextCtrl serve both purposes?  I know it does the text box but is it also the correct choice for the text field/text entry box?

**EDIT**
There are actually 2 types of text boxes for multi-line entry as pointed out in the answers.  What really interests me are widgets specific for single line entry versus widgets specific for multi-line entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxTextCtrl serves for both single and multiline entry.  It is quite powerful but not exactly 'word processor style'.  Closer to that would be wxRichTextCtrl.

wxComboBox uses wxTextEntry ( as does wxTextCtrl in single-line mode ).  Although wxTextEntry is not offered as a control itself - it does not inherit from wxControl - if you like it so much you might be able to build something using it.  But it seems like a lot of trouble for benefits that I do not see.

Comment: The wxTextEntry field used in wxComboBox I guess is the style I was looking for.  Too bad they didn't make such a thing available as a standalone widget because it is such a common widget.  wxTextCtrl it is for my text field needs.

Answer (score 0):

`wxTextCtrl` is a single line text control (what is called "entry" in other frameworks) by default. If you specify `wxTE_MULTILINE` style when creating it (this style can't be changed later), it becomes -- surprise -- a multi-line control, i.e. what is called "area" in other places.